# Docker image versioning and lifecycle management

Tags: docker, versioning, lifecycle

I am getting into Docker and am trying to better understand how it works out there in the "real world".

It occurs to me that, in practice:

- You need a way to version Docker images
- You need a way to tell the Docker engine (running on a VM) to stop/start/restart a particular container
- You need a way to tell the Docker engine which version of a image to run

Does Docker ship with built-in commands for handling each of these? If not what tools/strategies are used for accomplishing them? Also, when I build a Docker image (via, say, `docker build -t myapp .`), what file type is produced and where is it located on the machine?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56212495/properly-versioning-docker-images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docker has all you need to build images and run containers. You can create your own image by writing a Dockerfile or by pulling it from the docker hub.

In the Dockerfile you specify another image as the basis for your image, run command install things. Images can have tags, for example the ubuntu image can have the latest or 12.04 tag, that can be specified with `ubuntu:latest` notation.

Once you have built the image with `docker build -t image-name .` you can create containers from that image with `docker run --name container-name image-name.

`docker ps` to see running containers

`docker rm <container name/id>` to remove containers

Comment: I don't find this answer to be adequate, as there can be successive versions of the same tag. We need a way to be able to lock down dependencies onto a particular version of a tag. For example these tags all refer to different versions of the RMQ image: https://hub.docker.com/r/library/rabbitmq/tags/, but when someone recently made a change to the dockerfile and republished the image, it broke our prod RMQ when the docker host restarted and the latest image of that tag was pulled down.

Comment: @ReneWooller I think the answer is to not use `latest`. So in your case, start your Dockerfile with the line `FROM rabbitmq:3.6.1`

Comment: Good thinking but no, in the case I described, we were not using latest, but attempting to lock it to a particular version. There wouldn't be a problem if people tagged the versions with an additional version number for the docker file itself (eg rabbitmq:3.6.1_dv0.0.5) , but, crazily, the current standard approach is to tag on the version of whatever app the dockerfile is for. EG rabbitmq:3.6.1. The content of these tags can then  change behind the scenes with no ability to lock them down, other than forking the dockerfile.

Comment: @ReneWoller Maybe this wasn't possible when you wrote this, but now you can pull a specific image version by its digest like so: docker pull rabbitmq@sha256:<digest>
[ref](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-by-digest-immutable-identifier)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a docker file like bellow:

[image]

->Build from git without versioning:
**sudo docker build https://github.com/lordash/mswpw.git#fecomments:comments**

in here:
**fecomments** is branch name and **comments** is the folder name.

->building from git with tag and version:
**sudo docker build https://github.com/lordash/mswpw.git#fecomments:comments -t lordash/comments:v1.0**

->Now if you want to build from a directory: first go to comments directory the run command **sudo docker build .**

->if you want to add tag you can use **-t or -tag** flag to do that:
**sudo docker build -t lordash .** or **sudo docker build -t lordash/comments .**

-> Now you can version your image with the help of tag:
**sudo docker build -t lordash/comments:v1.0 .**

->you can also apply multiple tag to an image:
**sudo docker build -t lordash/comments:latest -t lordash/comments:v1.0 .**